# What is "1D strand texture coordinate" and "trail position" in Strand/Particle Coordinates

Tags: particles, texture-coordinates

From the manual on the blender internal texture page it explains

> Coordinates: Strand/Particle
>
> Uses normalized 1D strand texture coordinate or particle age (X) and trail >position (Y). Use when texture is applied to hair strands or particles.

While as I understand, particle age is mapped along X, what is the "1D strand texture coordinate" and "trail position" ?

Thank you.